# Copying stdin to stdout causes strange results

Tags: c#

I've got a super simple program. My intention is to copy standard input to standard output. Here's the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace LALA
{
    class LALA
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int bufferSize = 40;
            Console.OpenStandardInput().CopyTo(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), bufferSize);
        }
    }
}
```

If I set `bufferSize` to 40, then for any input I just see 'C o n', 'C o n s', or 'C o n s o l e' etc.
If I set `bufferSize` to 41, then everything is fine.

My question is am I doing something wrong, and by accident values above 41 work?

To clarify, this is the output when I type asd:

```
c:\some_path>ConsoleApplication2.exe
asd
C o n
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're observing. The code you've given works fine for me. What are you providing as input?

Comment: I run the program through cmd and write 'asd'. 
`C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Consol
eApplication2\bin\Debug>ConsoleApplication2.exe

asd

C o n^C`

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem via CMD.

Comment: I have absolutely no problems with running the executable file through CMD. Do you have some 'special' kind of compiling options on?

Comment: No, I did not modify any settings. They only thing that might be different is that I created that project under Visual C# 2008, discovered that the C# runtime boundled with it does not support CopyTo and installed Visual C# 2012 and used the same project.

Comment: What version of .NET? (4 or 4.5)

Comment: Currently I have .NET 4.5 installed

Comment: If I create a new project called 'DELETEME' then instead of seeing prefixes of Console I see prefixes of DELETEME.

Comment: I've got the same behavior in CMD (VS 2010, .Net4 - client profile, debug/release). Seem to be outputing program name only when buffer size is set to 40... No idea why (you may need try to type several strings with enter in between to repro).

Comment: It appears that [this is what is actually happening](http://i.stack.imgur.com/J6pXc.png). It is trying to write the name of the project which was ConsoleApplication2 in my case to the standard output stream based on the standard input stream.

Comment: So, I understand correctly that I can assume that my program is correct and there is a bug in my environment?

Comment: Your code just works fine (.NET 4.0, Visual Studio 2012, Build for Any CPU) and I can not reproduce what you say with any buffer size!

Comment: @Jon I did reproduce this phenomenon and reached an interesting conclusion; if you can take a quick look in my answer and let me know if it makes sense or utterly wrong it'll be great.

Answer (score 1):

Surprise! This appears to be internal buffer overflow and I'll share what I found, though it's not yet a real proof it makes sense to me.

The code for `CopyTo` method of the Stream class is: (taken with reflector)

```
public void CopyTo(Stream destination, int bufferSize)
{
    //bunch of non relevant validations...

    this.InternalCopyTo(destination, bufferSize);
}
```

Now the code for `InternalCopyTo` is:

```
private void InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, int bufferSize)
{
    byte[] array = new byte[bufferSize];
    int count;
    while ((count = this.Read(array, 0, array.Length)) != 0)
    {
        destination.Write(array, 0, count);
    }
}
```

The console stream instance is of type `__ConsoleStream` (sealed internal class in System.IO) and its `Read` method code:

```
public override int Read([In] [Out] byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    //bunch of non relevant validations...

    int errorCode = 0;
    int num = __ConsoleStream.ReadFileNative(this._handle, buffer, offset, count, 0, out errorCode);
    if (num == -1)
    {
        __Error.WinIOError(errorCode, string.Empty);
    }
    return num;
}
```

And finally `ReadFileNative` code of __ConsoleStream:

```
private unsafe static int ReadFileNative(SafeFileHandle hFile, byte[] bytes, int offset, int count, int mustBeZero, out int errorCode)
{
    if (bytes.Length - offset < count)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(Environment.GetResourceString("IndexOutOfRange_IORaceCondition"));
    }
    if (bytes.Length == 0)
    {
        errorCode = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    __ConsoleStream.WaitForAvailableConsoleInput(hFile);
    int result;
    int num;
    fixed (byte* ptr = bytes)
    {
        num = __ConsoleStream.ReadFile(hFile, ptr + (IntPtr)offset / 1, count, out result, Win32Native.NULL);
    }
    if (num != 0)
    {
        errorCode = 0;
        return result;
    }
    errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (errorCode == 109)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The `ReadFile` method is low level call:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private unsafe static extern int ReadFile(SafeFileHandle handle, byte* bytes, int numBytesToRead, out int numBytesRead, IntPtr mustBeZero);
```

My assumption at this point is that behind the scenes, 40 bytes are "reserved" somewhere to internal data so if the buffer is not more than that, you will see that reserved data which in this case of console application is the process name.

I will keep investigating this when I'll have more time and try to reproduce, this case is quite special since both streams point to the same "file" so you can write to it while reading it.